# Script that should be in Site Assets is missing

Tags: 2010, javascript

SharePoint 2010

I'm trying to track down a JS file to edit it, but I can't find it where it should be via SPD. In the page I can see the callout to it, and if I paste that URL into the browser it opens the script, but it doesn't appear to exist in that location in SPD or on the site itself.

The path is https://site-collection.com/sub-site/SiteAssets/Script.js

The Site Assets folder doesn't even appear when examining the site contents in the browser. It does show up in Designer, but does not contain the script. I've checked the parent (top-level site) but the script doesn't appear there either.

Does anyone know where I should be looking for this script?

Comment: is it related to blob cache? see this related post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47501/js-files-returning-cached-old-versions-despite-update

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately that isn't the case here; Ensuring all caches are cleared did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The script file should be deployed thought a module within a farm solution with such markup: `<File Path="Module1\JavaScript1.js" Url="SiteAssets/Script.js" />`. So the file lives on server but there is a "virtual" path to it. 
If the setting Type="GhostableInLibrary" were added in the module, you should be able to see it through the Designer. However, you wan't see the file though the browser because there is no Site Assets library created.

Comment: What's weird though is that if I paste the path to this file into the browser, it opens.